# Recursive function pattern

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

What is a general-purpose 'template' for how a recursive function might look, without using a `yield` operator? What I have so far is something like:

```
RETURN_CONDITION    = '...'
VALUE_ON_RETURN     = '...'
CHANGE_ARG_FUNCTION = lambda args: ...
REDUCER_FUNCTION    = lmabda args: ...

def recursive_function(*args):
    funcname = traceback.extract_stack()[-2][2]
    print ("Called %s(%s)", (funcname,', '.join(args)))
    if arg == RETURN_CONDITION:
        return VALUE_ON_RETURN
    else:
        new_args = CHANGE_ARG_FUNCTION(args)
        res = REDUCER_FUNCTION (recursive_function(new_args))
        print("Intermediate result for args %s = %s" % (new_args, res))
        return res
```

Does it seem like I have most covered, or are there other things that I might be missing in a general-purpose template?

Comment: I wrote this answer months ago that might be of relevance: [`How to rewrite a program to use recursion?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58705443/how-to-rewrite-a-program-to-use-recursion/58706233#58706233). It is, however, specific to the question the OP there had posted.

Comment: @Felipe that's great. Thank you

Comment: Reducer function should be called additionally with the args, e.g. `REDUCER_FUNCTION (args, recursive_function(new_args))`. E. g. for a simple recursive faculty function the reducer needs to know which number the recursive result must be multiplied with.

Comment: My pleasure. Doesn't answer your question directly but it might be of some help. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rewrite a program to use recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58705443/how-to-rewrite-a-program-to-use-recursion)