# Writing an abstract reducer function for recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, recursion, iteration

I am trying to generalize a factorial function, and I'm having trouble adding in a 'reducer' function to, for example:

```
def factorial(n):
    if FACTORIAL_RETURN_CONDITION(n=1):
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1) # this line -- how to 'combine' n with factorial(n-1)
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
import traceback

RETURN_CONDITION  = lambda **kwargs: kwargs['n'] == 1  # if n=1, we quit
RETURN_VALUE      = lambda **kwargs: 1                  # we could just write '1' here but keep it in lambda so can easily change
DELTA             = lambda **kwargs: (exec("kwargs['n']-=1"),kwargs)[1]
REDUCER           = lambda **kwargs: ???


def func(**kwargs):
    args_as_str = ', '.join([f'{k}={v!r}' for k,v in kwargs.items()])
    print ("Called func(%s)" % args_as_str)
    if RETURN_CONDITION(**kwargs):
        return RETURN_VALUE()
    else:
        res = kwargs['n'] * func(**DELTA(**kwargs)) # how to get rid of this line and use the reducer?
        print ("Returning intermediate result: %s" % res, kwargs)
        return res
```

It is very abstract and overkill for the above, but I'm basically trying to figure out general recursion patterns and abstract away the variables/conditions into a general template. What might be an example way to write the below 'reducer' function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rewrite a program to use recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58705443/how-to-rewrite-a-program-to-use-recursion)

Comment: @Grismar no -- I've already read that. it's a great answer, but I'm just looking to figure out how to write a reducer function, if possible here.